# Error building two different files from same tree with broccoli-requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, lodash, broccolijs

I'm trying to compile two different JS files using [broccoli-requirejs](https://github.com/aaronshaf/broccoli-requirejs). A logical way to go about this seemed to be to run the requireJs filter on my scripts tree twice, with two different configurations. Doing so produces some really strange errors that, to me, resembles a race condition or something.

See below for Broccoli config and error output.

```
var compileCoffee = require("broccoli-coffee"),
    compileStatic = require("broccoli-static-compiler"),
    mergeTrees    = require("broccoli-merge-trees"),
    requireJs     = require("broccoli-requirejs"),
    _             = require("lodash");

var scripts = compileStatic("app/coffee", {
    srcDir: "/",
    destDir: "scripts"
});
scripts = compileCoffee(scripts, {bare: true});

var rjsOptions = {
    baseUrl: "scripts",
    inlineText: true,
    optimize: "uglify",
    stubModules: ["text"],
    paths: {
        knockout: "empty:"
    }
};

var fooScript = requireJs(scripts, {
    requirejs: _.extend(rjsOptions, {
        include: ["foo"],
        insertRequire: ["main"],
        mainConfigFile: "scripts/main.js",
        name: "main",
        out: "scripts/main.js"
    })
});

var barScript = requireJs(scripts, {
    requirejs: _.extend(rjsOptions, {
        insertRequire: ["bar"],
        mainConfigFile: "scripts/main.js",
        name: "bar",
        out: "scripts/bar.js"
    })
});

module.exports = mergeTrees([
    fooScript,
    barScript
]);
```

I get the following error when building this:

```
$ broccoli build build
Error: Merge error: file scripts/bar.js exists in /home/fredrik/app/tmp/require_js_filter-tmp_dest_dir-yMHQNi3F.tmp and /home/fredrik/app/tmp/require_js_filter-tmp_dest_dir-C8Wv970J.tmp
Pass option { overwrite: true } to mergeTrees in order to have the latter file win.
  at mergeRelativePath (/home/fredrik/app/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/index.js:98:21)
  at mergeRelativePath (/home/fredrik/app/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/index.js:122:17)
  at /home/fredrik/app/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/index.js:23:5
  at $$$internal$$tryCatch (/home/fredrik/app/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:490:16)
  at $$$internal$$invokeCallback (/home/fredrik/app/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:502:17)
  at $$$internal$$publish (/home/fredrik/app/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:473:11)
  at Object.$$rsvp$asap$$flush [as _onImmediate] (/home/fredrik/app/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1581:9)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:345:15)


Build failed
```

And if I do pass `{overwrite: true}` to the mergeTrees call, I get the output of the first requireJs call (ie. the `scripts/main.js`), *but with the filename bar.js*.

Comment: You can reuse the same tree multiple times; there's no need to duplicate them. That's what you seem to be doing in your code sample already, passing `scripts` into the `requireJs` calls for `fooScript` and `barScript`. Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: @JoLiss I added a better description of the actual error to the question. Let me know if that makes sense!

I think it dawned on me at some point that maybe it wasn't that I needed to duplicate the tree, but the issue almost looks like a race condition or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my problem was totally unrelated to both Broccoli and broccoli-requirejs. It's my call to `_.extend` that overwrites rjsConfig object. And since the actual r.js optimization with its of the config object doesn't happen before the trees are merged, the result of the second `_.extend` call is passed in twice.

Simply changing the order of the arguments passed to `_.extend` made it work as expected:

```
var fooScript = requireJs(scripts, {
    requirejs: _.extend({
        include: ["foo"],
        insertRequire: ["main"],
        mainConfigFile: "scripts/main.js",
        name: "main",
        out: "scripts/main.js"
    }, rjsOptions)
});
```